# How to save audio to documents in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I tried to record an audio and save it to documents folder, but the program can only work in simulator. Once I run it in my iPhone(ios 8.3), it cannot work. Is there something wrong with my codes? Thank you.

Here is h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioRecorder.h>
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
}

- (IBAction)REC:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)STOP_and_SAVE:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PLAY:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Record_path1_string;


@end
```

m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)REC:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    self.Record_path1_string = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bbb.wav"];
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: self.Record_path1_string] settings:nil error:nil];

    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    [recorder record];

    NSLog(@"recording!");
}

- (IBAction)STOP_and_SAVE:(id)sender {
    [recorder stop];
}

- (IBAction)PLAY:(id)sender {
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: self.Record_path1_string] error:nil];
    [player play];
}

@end
```

I have checked the Documents folder in simulator in my Mac, the audio file has been saved, but I cannot check Documents folder in my iPhone.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error, or do you mean you just can't see the documents directory to check the file exists?

Comment: Thank you sir, you are the first one answering me.  When I run this application in my iPhone, no error will appear but I just cannot hear the audio recorded. And I also use:

Comment: if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.Record_path1_string] == NO) {
        self.Label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"No audio file to delete."];
        NSLog(@"Del 0.1");
    }
    else{
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:self.Record_path1_string error:NULL];
        
        self.Label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Audio file exists!"];
        NSLog(@"Del 0.2");
    }

Comment: to detect the file, but it didn't exist.